# Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, rest-assured

Cannot deserialize Json into List collection. I'm using Lombok, that hold field variables:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "success")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AparsersResponceDto {
  private Integer success;
  private ArrayList<String> data;
}
```

RestAssured controller that do post request to API:

```
public ValidatableResponse getFirstAparserStatus(AparsersDto toGetAparser) {
    return RestAssured
            .given().spec(getDefaultRequestSpecification())
            .body(toGetAparser)
            .when()
            .post(apars141 + port1)
            .then()
            .log().all();
}
```

And do extract body of the post request:

```
private AparsersController aparsersController = new AparsersController();


public AparsersResponceDto postFirstBody(AparsersDto aparsersDto) {
    return aparsersController
            .getFirstAparserStatus(aparsersDto) //Sent post request with the body aparsersDto through RestAssured
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract().body().as(AparsersResponceDto.class); // Here i can't make extract of the 'data' field due to collection List. 
}
```

Response Json:

```
"success": 1,
"data": {
    "45.90.34.87:59219": [
        "http"
    ],
    "144.76.108.82:41049": [
        "http"
    ],
    "5.9.72.48:59473": [
        "http"
    ],
    "130.0.232.208:49327": [
        "http"
    ],
    "217.172.179.54:39492": [
        "http"
    ],
    ...
```

Complite error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.rest.dto.AparsersResponceDto["data"])
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: The error message and you class do not match. Error state `ArrayList<StringBuilder>` but you class do not have any member with type `ArrayList<StringBuilder>`. Is the code posted is the complete code.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Sorry, Inattentively copied. Already fixed it and add further information.

Comment: `data` field in your json is not an `ArayList` it looks like a `Map<String,List<String>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` in the JSON is not an `ArrayList<String>` instead it is a `Map<String,List<String>>`

So change you DTO as follows.

```java
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "success")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AparsersResponceDto {
   private Integer success;
   private Map<String,List<String>> data;
}
```